# How to Preprocess 'Cats vs Dogs' Tensorflow Datasets in order to deal with it in CNN?

Tags: conv-neural-network

I have a problem about dealing with data preprocession of tensorflow 'cats vs dogs' datasets

I loaded data like this:

`dataset, info = tfds.load(name='cats_vs_dogs, split=tfds.Split.TRAIN, with_info=True)`

Then, I'd like to define preprocess function like this:

`def preprocess(features):`

Then, I'd like to use this preprocess function like this:

`train_dataset = dataset.map(preprocess).batch(32)`

where `train_dataset` is the train set that I would use in fitting my model.

However, I have no idea how to preprocess my loaded data. Specifically, I don't even know what sort of data type `dataset` is.
Please help me to solve this problem. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Here you can refer to this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#decoding_image_data_and_resizing_it) to learn more about tensorflow datasets and input pipelines, to prepare the data you can use this function

```
def preprocess(features):
    print(features['image'], features['label'])
    image = tf.image.resize(features['image'], [224,224])
    image = tf.divide(image, 255)
    print(image)
    label = features['label']
    print(label)
    return image, tf.cast(label, tf.float32)
```

hope this helps, By the way don't use softmax in your model use sigmoid instead

Answer (score -2):

First, you need to study the dataset.

Then you can preproccess the dataset in order to make the dataset in same size of images. here 200 * 200 images have been taken.

```
  from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
  from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array

  X = []
  img= load_img(file_path, target_size=(200, 200))
  img= img_to_array(img)
  X.append(img)
```

For every image, You need to do this before training and testing.

Then you can split the dataset into two different parts as training_data and testing_data.
Typically taking 70% and 30% respectively is better. for this you may use

```
   from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
   Xtrain, Xtest, Ytrain, Ytest = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.30)
```

Thank you!